# Conda cannot create environment from a .yml file

Tags: conda, miniconda

I have reinstalled conda and now trying to recreate an environment from previously exported `env.yml`.

With

```
conda env create --name mapping --file=env.yml
```

The only promt I get is
`[y/N]:`
and nothing happens, the env is not created.

What is wrong and how to fix it?

P.S. conda is fresh and was just re-installed.

Comment: Now everyone is wondering about the contents of env.yml and whether you did a clean uninstall (https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/uninstall/ before the re-install.

Comment: yes, I did a clean uninstall as described. and contents of env.yml does not really matter, because apparently the same error occurs which I do conda env remove. i suspect the problem's not in the environment.